# Java: How to use a counter in register using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted the ID was 1,2,3,4 each new name, ie

ID - Name - Age

1 - Paul - 60

2 - Regis - 25

3 - Ana - 20

automatic ID

```
static void register(ArrayList mylist) {
        int i = 1;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Peoples p = new Peoples();
//        System.out.print("ID: ");
//        p.ID = in.nextInt();
        p.ID = i;
        i++;
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        p.name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        p.age = in.nextInt();
        mylist.add(p);
    }


public class Peoples {
    public int ID;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would slightly modified the `Peoples` class (btw. it is a goood practice to use a singular for class names).

```
public class Person {
    private static int lastId;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
      id = Person.lastId++;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jiri Kremser. Rohit Jain, your code not working. I used code for Jiri Kremser. Thanks.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva. Ah!! Sorry for that.. You need to declare that variable `i` in my code as `static`.. But still, `Jiri` has given you far better way to solve.. So, you can ignore mine :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your variable `i = 1` outside the method.. Because you don't want it to get initialized to same value on every method call..

```
static int i = 1;
static void register(ArrayList mylist) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Peoples p = new Peoples();
        p.ID = i++;   // You can do increment + assignment on the same line.
     // i++;  // No need to increment in separate line
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        p.name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        p.age = in.nextInt();
        mylist.add(p);
    }
```